# keypress,keyup and change events on inputs with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table where the first row are all text inputs sharing the same class name. i would like to set a validation so that user only enters float numbers. Does anyone know what i may be missing on the following code? $('input.' + classname) or  $('.classname) doesn't fire any event when calling floatTextField() function

HTML code:

```
<td><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control myclass" value="2.8"></div> </td>
```

JavaScript code:

```
floatTextField('myclass');
function floatTextField(classname) {
    $('input.' + classname).keypress(function (event) {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        if (event.which == 0)//common keys
            return true;
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (charCode == 45 && value.indexOf('-') != -1) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (charCode == 46 && value.indexOf('.') != -1)
            return false;
        else if (charCode != 46 && charCode != 45 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    });
    $('input.' + classname).keyup(function (event) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value <= 0 && value.indexOf('.') == -1 && value.indexOf('-') == -1) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        if (value.indexOf('-') > 0) {
            value = value.replace('-', '');
            $(this).val(value);
        }
    });
    $('input.' + classname).change(function (event) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value.indexOf('.') == 0) {
            value = '0' + value;
            $(this).val(value);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you like include [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jtu0uh1b/2/) made with your code in your question. I have added a `console.log()` to all events and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `$(document).ready()` method like this:

```
function floatTextField(classname) {
    $('input.' + classname).keypress(function (event) {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        if (event.which == 0)//common keys
            return true;
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (charCode == 45 && value.indexOf('-') != -1) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (charCode == 46 && value.indexOf('.') != -1)
            return false;
        else if (charCode != 46 && charCode != 45 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    });
    $('input.' + classname).keyup(function (event) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value <= 0 && value.indexOf('.') == -1 && value.indexOf('-') == -1) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        if (value.indexOf('-') > 0) {
            value = value.replace('-', '');
            $(this).val(value);
        }
    });
    $('input.' + classname).change(function (event) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value.indexOf('.') == 0) {
            value = '0' + value;
            $(this).val(value);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  floatTextField('myclass');
});
```

Comment: yes, the function is within $(document).ready(function(){}, and it works when i'm using $("#myId").click(function(){})

Comment: Do you want your code to fire the events in your function every time it is called?

Comment: i want to fire any of the events whithin the function whenever user enters values on any of the input texts